# Split a double-line character column into two columns in R

Tags: r, split, character

I would like to split a double-line character column into two columns in R.

For instance, turn the character column below:

```
"0311I250 61I272 62E669                                                                                                                                                            03 I250 E669 I272"
```

into two columns

```
## "0311I250 61I272 62E669" "03 I250 E669 I272".
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide some more information on the logic of this split.  For example, is the split on the third space, or after a fixed number of characters?

Comment: `strsplit(your_string, '\\s{2,}')[[1]]`

Comment: I'd go for `data.table::tstrsplit(x, "\\n")` but there are a lot of other options in the link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strsplit at blank with two digits after it.

```
unlist(strsplit(string,'(\\s)(?=\\d{2}\\s+)',perl=T))
[1] "0311I250 61I272 62E669" "03 I250 E669 I272"
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!